# Are Prepared Statements JDBC JAVA requests similar to those of PHP?

Tags: java, php, jdbc, prepared-statement

For example, this query is similar in two languages :

```
    "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?"
```

But in JAVA following query is not working :

```
    "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=:name"
```

Are there a more friendly way than using a suite of interrogation points in JAVA ?

Comment: You can do the `:name` in PHP as well, that is a named parameter (depending on the driver you are using). http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC `PreparedStatement` is **similar** (but not **identical** to) PHP `PreparedStatement`, when using JDBC bind parameters (`parameterIndex`) is an `int`. See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps) and the [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) Javadoc. Assuming you have a `Connection conn` and a `String name`, it might be done with something like

```
String sql = "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setString(1, name);
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("District"));
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The answer to my question looks to be no. Thank you for your detailling contribution.